# Haskell converting string to binary number

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming, binary

I need to convert a string of chars to a list of binary numbers in Haskell. I've written two functions to do this, but I'm not sure how to combine them into one. So far I have

```
dec[]=[]
dec(x:xs) = ord(x): dec xs
```

to convert every char in the list into a decimal number. The next function

```
bin 0 = [0]
bin n| n `mod` 2 == 1 = bin (n `div` 2) ++ [1]
     | n `mod` 2 == 0 = bin (n `div` 2) ++ [0]
```

converts a decimal number to its binary equivalent. I'm not sure how to apply the second function to every element in the list, in order to convert every char to its equivalent in binary. I tried to use the `where` clause:

`where n = dec(x:xs) = ord(x): dec xs`

but this is not valid as there are two equals signs on the same line. How can I achieve the correct functionality?

Comment: Can you give an example (or a few examples) of the input and output you want?

Comment: @DanielWagner Let's say I give the function the string "ab0" I want it to output   [ 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 1):

You can be pretty certain that an `Int` will be stored in binary.  It only appears to be in decimal because it is converted to decimal when you print it.  So, the name `dec` is a misnomer, that function is converting a `String` into a sequence of numbers that represent the Unicode value of each character.  You can avoid explicit recursion by using map:

```
toUnicode :: String -> [Int]
toUnicode = map ord
```

Note that this function uses so-called point-free style.  The expected argument is missing, but will be passed to `map` when supplied by the caller.

The `Bin` function will not compile because it starts with an upper case character, making it a data constructor.  You should name the function starting with a lower case character.  According to your example output, you want leading zeros in your binary representations, so you can't stop conversion when the value becomes zero.  You need to continue until you have converted the desired number of digits, which appears to be 8.  It is also inefficient to keep appending to a list.  It is better to prepend, and then reverse the result.

```
toBinary :: Int -> [Int]
toBinary = go 8 [] where
    go 0 acc _ = reverse acc
    go n acc x = go (n-1) (bit:acc) x' where
        (x', bit) = x `divMod` 2
```

Here, we use a helper function, `go` which counts down the number of remaining digits as it builds up the list of 1's and 0's.

So, now we have a function to convert a `String` into a list of `Int`s, and a function to convert an `Int` into a list of 0/1 `Int`s, and we want to glue them together to make a function that converts a `String` to a list of 0/1 `Int`s.  If we `map` our `toBinary` function over the result of `toUnicode`, we will get a list of lists, which must be concatenated to form a single list.  This is such a common pattern that there's a function for that called, `concatMap`:

```
stringToBinary :: String -> [Int]
stringToBinary = concatMap toBinary . toUnicode
```

Here we use function composition to first apply `toUnicode` to the `String`, and then `concatMap` the `toBinary` over the result.

Comment: Note that if you include any characters that has a Unicode value greater than 255, the upper bits of the binary representation will be elided.

Answer (score -1):

What we want is a function of type `String -> String` (`decimal -> binary`). What you have now is

```
dec :: String -> [Int]
bin :: Int -> [Int] -- use *lowercase*
```

So it seems impossible to compose a function of type `String -> String` only with these two. Besides, `ord` is not what you want.

```
*Main> dec "123"
[49,50,51]
*Main> bin 123
[0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]
```

From what you have now, the possible solution would be:

```
*Main Data.Char> toBinary = map intToDigit . bin . read
*Main Data.Char> toBinary "123"
"01111011"
```

I guess your intention may be `dec :: String -> Int`, then `bin . dec :: String -> [Int]`. You can follow the type signature and retry.